# React Router - Go back to the last page visited, and not the default component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am having a bit of an issue with React Router that I can not seem to figure out. It does not go back to the very last page visited, rather the first page it loaded. Here is an example.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './utils/auth/PrivateRoute';
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardView} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/games" component={Games} />
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path="/viewgame/:id*/"
        component={SingleGameView}
      />
    </Router>
```

When you go to `/dashboard`, you can click to view a games list that takes you to `/games`. You can then click on a game to see a single view of it, which takes you to `/viewgame/:id*`

Like so: /dashboard -> /games -> /viewgame/:id*

When you click on a game and are taken to `/viewgame/`, and then decide to click back in the browser, it takes me back to `/dashboard` instead of taking me back to /games. It is skipping over the last visited page, and taking me back to the first loaded page. I can send someone back to a route by setting up my own 'click to go back' button, but I need the browsers actual back and forward button to do this.

`PrivateRoute` is a HOC I setup to check to make sure the user accessing the route is authenticated or not. Otherwise they are booted. In case that could be the issue here is that component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

//Utils - Auth
import { userAuth } from '../../../authentication/authentication';
const { isAuthenticated } = userAuth;

//Checks if a user isAuthenticated. If so, it renders the passed in secure component. If not, it renders a redirect to /signin
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Here’s a snapshot of the PrivateRoute props when it’s rendered a component: [image]

Comment: If you are using `props.history.replace()` when navigating from `/games` to `/viewgame/id*`, it would replace that history entry causing the browser to go back to the dashboard. If that is what is happening in your code, you should use `props.history.push()` instead.

Comment: Using the react extension in your browser, what do the props look like on each of your `<PrivateRoute>` components at each stage? Do they have the route props?

Comment: @technicallynick hey thanks for the comment and excuse the late reply. The props in the PrivateRoute components show the location object and also the path, but I do not see any previous route props or anything related.

Comment: How are your links setup in the DashboardView and Games components?  Are you using react-router `<Link />` or `history.push()`?

Comment: A repro on codesandbox or the like might be required. I don't see anything in your code that immediately points to the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by calling `goBack()` function in `history` object inside `withRouter()`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export default withRouter(({ history }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>BACK</button>
    </div>
  )
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is what @maison.m is asking for. He said he "... can send someone back to a route by setting up [his] own 'click to go back' button, but [he] need the browsers actual back and forward button to do this." This solution is simply adding a button to the page for the user to hit to go back, rather than the built in/native button in the users browser.

Comment: ReactRouter has [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) package as a dependency, which uses browser session history. In this case `history.goBack()` takes you to the last page visited. More about history API [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history). I don't know if this is what @maison.m wanted, but I think that this could help him in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `useHistory` hook from react-router-dom

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();

...

<div onClick={ ()=>history.goBack() }>Back </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove 'exact' from your routes props.